# Sending outbound HTTP request from Akka / Scala

Tags: facebook, scala, couchdb, akka

I know how to [handle incoming http requests](http://doc.akka.io/http) in Akka, but I want my Akka-based web app also to communicate with Facebook and CouchDB through HTTP APIs by sending outbound calls. Is there any good practice of this? Should calls be async?

Comment: the link is dead. do you have another one?

Answer (score 4):

For Couch Debasish has SCouchDB: https://github.com/debasishg/scouchdb

As for speaking with Facebook, I do not know, but if you want to do async http outbound calls you can try: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

A little while back, I posted a sample WebGL app using Akka talking to Facebook and Google Maps.  It's nothing special, but it may help.  You can find it here:  https://github.com/dsciamma/fbgl1