# Interactive Java Software Architecture

Tags: java, architecture, executorservice

We designed a software architecture a while ago which processed transactions. It worked like this: Incoming events, based on their type, were translated into `Callable`'s which then run into an `Executor` based on the event type. For example, "Event_A" type gets converted into `EventAHandler` (a `Callable`), then run in an `Executor`.

We now have to support interactive events, i.e, events which need further input from the user over the network, which is slow. For example, for the new type of event, we present a menu to the user and wait for the response. If we follow the architecture described above, i.e., turn each event into a `Callable`, we tie up threads waiting for user response which isn't a good idea.

I'm looking for suggestions or architectural styles to let us do this. We need to support around 10,000 events a second. I'd like to stick to the Executor Framework and cannot change the system to support an async loop, if possible.

Comment: Callable implies Future which implies get() which is blocking. If you are building truly asynchronous application, you need not Callable. If you really use Callable, your application is not fully asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

using [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) based architecture maybe fit your needs, [akka](/questions/tagged/akka) is a well known implementation of this paradigm.

Comment: That's something I considered. It won't work because Actors should not block on some external action (Source: [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293707/java-example-for-sending-non-blocking-http-request-from-akka)) This gives the same effect as creating a `Callable` or `Runnable`, having a thread in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` check it out, and then the whole thread blocks.... Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to represent your architecture as a [Data flow diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram). It can be dynamic, where new nodes are created during execution. Instead of waiting a user response, create a new node which would react to that response, and route the response to that node. This way you never block a thread.

Then, realize what properties of the dataflow graph elements you need, such as:

- does a node react to multiple subsequent messages (like an object) or used to process a single message (like a method call)
- does a node have single input, or multiple inputs
- if multiple inputs, should the node fire execution when all inputs are filled (AND gate) or when any input is filled (OR gate)

-- etc

Then decide which dataflow/actor library would fit your requirements. I would not exclude Akka, but I recommend mine development [df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j) as it is compact, extendable, and supports multi-input nodes out of the box.